# Describing a person who changing his opinion too frequent

Tags: proverbs

Is there a proverb describing a person who changing his opinion too frequent?

Need a proverb which will have a bit negative meaning to describe a person who is inconsistent in his opinions.

Comment: Or you could say that a person [*waffles*, or is *a waffler*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/waffle).

Comment: Person who changes opinions too frequently and is overall inconsistent? You may try "politician" :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say that person is **flip-flopping** (typically on some issue in particular).

**To blow hot and cold** is another, more general but seemingly less widely used idiom.

Comment: +1 for *blow hot and cold*, though.